# Histogram image not getting saved

Tags: python, histogram

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.random.gamma( 2, 3, 100000)

plt.hist( x, bins=30)

plt.show()

plt.savefig("normalhistogram.png")
```

The above code is working perfectly for plotting histograms for gama distribution values, but the only problem is that I want to save the image of generated histogram but `plt.savefig("normalhistogram.png")` is creating a blank image everytime I execute the code instead of saving the histogram as image. I'm unable to figure out the issue here. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not `show()` the image before saving it. Showing the image clears the canvas. (But saving does not, so you can show the image after saving it.)